# Why is monerod so slow to sync the blockchain?

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Only a few days can take more than an hour to sync. It couldn't simply be a matter of downloading x MBs as I download much larger files much faster. Is there ***that*** much processing going on, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Access to the database file (data.mdb) can be very slow if you are using a HDD for storage, because of the fragmentation of the database. Using a SSD improves things a lot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems to be equally slow despite the new improvements with the latest release. The overall size however was greatly reduced from 17GB to 9GB. Were the improvements only for storage size, or also for access speed? I look forward to a new computer that will have SSD.

Comment: With a mid-range two-core CPU (i5-6200), and an SSD, I synced in exactly one hour. SSD does change everything.